# asp.net fileupload value to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using formview for inserting data into my database.I have to store name of an image file using file upload.Code is doing good with textbox.I just need guidance that how to connect that fileupload via form view.

code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
DefaultMode="Insert">

<InsertItemTemplate>
  Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="shop_nameTextBox" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("shop_name") %>' />
    <br />
    shop_image:
    <asp:TextBox ID="shop_imageTextBox" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("shop_image") %>'  />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />
    <br />

    shop_desc:
    <asp:TextBox ID="shop_descTextBox" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("shop_desc") %>' />
    <br />


    shop_contact:
    <asp:TextBox ID="shop_contactTextBox" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("shop_contact") %>' />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
        CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />

    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
        CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
</InsertItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
```

I have tried to connect text box to file upload control but in vain. Googling has also not paid off.

Comment: Are you trying to get the filename from the fileupload control?

Comment: yes I have to get the filename in the textbox.

Comment: Just `FileUpload1.FileName` will give you the filename right?

Comment: but attribute Text='<%# Bind("shop_image") %>' for textbox already exists.How to add the file name ?

Comment: After uploading the file, you will save the file locally and send only the file name, along with other details to the db right?

Comment: @user2125727 "how to connect that fileupload via form view." what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your dilemma correctly the following should provide a solution, [taken from here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>

protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                if(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File " + FileUploadControl.FileName + " uploaded!";
                }
                else
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!";
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: Yes it is possible to do this inside an inserttemplate, the trick is to use the FindControl method something like as follows:

```
protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormView formView = (FormView)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent;
    FileUpload fileUpload1 = (FileUpload)formView.FindControl("FileUpload1");

    if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = fileUpload1.FileName;
        //do inserting or uploading as you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible in insert template of a form view ?

Comment: @user2125727 Yes it is, see my 'update' section. Perhaps you should consider binding the image to an <img> control and using the TextBox / Label to display file upload information?